# Why does chrome show a different value when the object is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

Chrome is showing different value when an object is opened

{coords: Array(0), mainLat: "", mainLng: ""}

and when the object is open it shows

coords: "[{"lng":-73.9865711,"lat":40.7616564},{"lng":-73.9808822,"lat":40.7592733},{"lng":-73.9841142,"lat":40.7548421},{"lng":-73.9808875,"lat":40.7534788},{"lng":-73.9730126,"lat":40.7642791},{"lng":-73.9790744,"lat":40.7668754},{"lng":-73.9800319,"lat":40.7655204},{"lng":-73.9828759,"lat":40.7667118},{"lng":-73.9865711,"lat":40.7616564}]"
mainLat: 40.7622684
mainLng: -73.9795443

I am using an object in JavaScript to store the values